# System automatically shuts down

Tags: shutdown

My laptop automatically shut downs  itself.

I thought that it could be a RAM problem since I had purchased a new ram stick 20 days earlier.

So I tested it through memtest.But my laptop produces a long continuous beep and then shut downs itself.

So is it a RAM problem or something else is the cause.

Also it shuts down even in bios.

So what is the case and can anyone tell me what is the reason of long beep in memtest86 I have searched for it but didn't found any sources

Comment: Test it without the new RAM, then test again with **only** the new RAM.

Comment: Sounds like an overheating CPU

Comment: Also the keyboard broke,meaning keys weren't working so do you guys think that dust could be a factor.

Comment: I could test it but now I don't have the screw gauge for opening screws and it's lockdown for electrical shops

Comment: Did you check the manual of the laptop what this beep means?

Comment: When was the last time you cleaned the laptop air vents with canned air?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am posting this as it may help others.
The problem was that the inner circuit consisting of mouse and keyboard were shorted and that is why computer itself shutdown to prevent any damage.
Other causes for unexpected shutdowns may be defective ram,overheating cpu,or dust in your machine,or problem with power supply.